# Why not Dispose always?

Tags: c#, dispose

I know this question has already been asked, but my question is more general than the others I've seen.

When I was checking in my program my use of controls in `Forms`, and commands for `DB`(Commands, Readers, etc), the following question came to me:

If I have a Control, shouldn't I `Dispose` it after I use it?

That way I will make sure that my program is using only the resources that are needed, and if I must use a control that was already disposed then I'll just load it again.

Maybe there's a reason to not dispose everything always, but that's why I'm asking this question.

Thanks for any answer and I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: You didn't even mention or tag which language you are talking about. I guess C#?

Comment: Yes C#. I added the tag. Thanks

Comment: " And if I must use a control that was disposed " oh but you wouldn't have disposed off something if you must use later, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150735/why-would-i-need-to-call-dispose-on-asp-net-controls may help

Comment: you have "some kind of control". Can you clarify? The control lifecycle is most of time exactly the owner window's one, as it fits in the component collection pattern. "After I use it"? How do you use your control? And to answer, dispose object you created at the end of its use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if no concrete reason speaks against it, you probably should dispose everything. Controls are automatically disposed of when in a `Form` and the `Form` is disposed.

Not disposing of UI resources is not very harmful. It is just a little more memory are system resource usage than necessary. This is in most cases not a functional problem.

This is in contrast to database connections and files, of course! Disposing of them is critical.

Comment: If disposing is critical, then something is broken.  It should always be possible (and, for some value of the word, "safe") to not dispose.

Comment: @cHao I don't think that is true: Think of files being locked for an indeterminate amount of time because a FileStream was not disposed. Or a transaction leaking into the next HTTP request because it was not ended in the previous request. Both examples are permanent problems for stability. They cause random behavior. They are a *must fix*.

Comment: And both examples are of other brokenness.  If you need for a file to be available immediately, you *close it*.  If you don't want that transaction active in the next request, you *roll it back or commit it*.  Both are broken examples of abusing `Dispose` to do things it shouldn't be doing.  It has one job, and that job ain't rolling back your transaction for you.  *That should already have been done*, if you're using transactions worth a damn.

Answer (score 7):

Non-visual components you create (commands, readers, I/O components, basically anything that implements `IDisposable`) should be disposed after you're done with them.

For visual controls, the `Form`'s `Dispose` function should dispose of all controls in it's `Controls` collection automatically, so you would only need to worry about controls that you remove from the form's `Controls` for some reason.

Unless you're experiencing serious memory problems it's probably a micro-optimization to try and dispose of form controls manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using using unmanaged resources, then yes. Go ahead and implement [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), that with the use of [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will simplify your work. But not always, as for your question. Your control (UI Control) implements already this IDisposable and will be called by its parent when closing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should. In Windows Forms windows (or within containers, respectively) the Form designer does it for you:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if(disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```